# Set multi columns in combobox after choosing a one position from a list

Tags: ms-access, vba

Combobox get data from this query:

```
select 
       ProductID
       ,Name
       ,ShortName
from Product
```

When I want to choose the position in combobox it's ok i see all the columns, but when i choose one product then in combobox i see only ProductID. 
Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That's by design. It shows the first column having a ColumnWidth larger than zero.

If you wish more info, modify the query to, for example:

```
Select [ProductID] & " - " &  [ShortName], [ProductId], [Name], ShortName From Product
```

Bind it to the second column (index 1), and set columnwidth of ProductId to zero.